# AuthenticationFailed with Azure node.js SDK's createContainerIfNotExist method

Tags: node.js, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to connect to the blog storage service with the Azure node.js sdk.  This is what I am calling:

```
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(nconf.get("BlobStorage.account"),
                                          nconf.get("BlobStorage.key"));

blobService.createContainerIfNotExist(
    "test1"
    , {publicAccessLevel : 'blob'}
    , function(error){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
});
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
code: 'AuthenticationFailed',
message: 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:7ff326e7-2bc6-47ad-898e-2235dc26c03d\nTime:2013-03-15T19:45:25.0167404Z',
authenticationerrordetail: 'The MAC signature found in the HTTP request \'xg3cY11YCPo3mYPxDF5UV7cTPOErleERogcozwGVm6s=\' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: \'PUT\n\n\n0\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-public-access:blob\nx-ms-date:Fri, 15 Mar 2013 19:45:25 GMT\nx-ms-version:2011-08-18\n/[containername removed for post]/test1%3Frestype=container\'.'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to resolve this issue?

Additional Details:

- running on local machine, accessing azure blobstorage in the cloud
- OS: Mountain Lion and Windows 8
- Node version: 0.10.0
- Azure NodeJS SDK version: 0.6.10

### UPDATE - 3/15/13 1:23pm

Appears there is an issue with azure nodejs sdk 0.6.10 and node 0.10.
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/645

Comment: You should accept an answer to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Azure NodeJS SDK supports nodeJS upto 0.8.x for now.

Answer (score 0):

@user1144313 we're aware that it's not working and are looking into it. http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2013/03/18/node-0-10-compat-issues-with-the-azure-sdk-and-cli/

For now please use node 0.8.x. As soon as we have the fixes in we'll be shipping updated versions. You can also check out wikis at https://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-for-node and https://github.com/windowsazure/azure-sdk-tools which we will update as soon as we release updates.

Sorry for any inconvenience.